# How to, from a list, filter it and convert to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-stream, collectors

I am trying to, from a list of Strings, filter it, and load the results into a `Map<String,String>` of with the strings that passed through the test and a generic reason.

This is why I am trying:

```
Map<String,String> invalidStrings = null;

invalidStrings = src.getAllSubjects()
                 .stream()
                 .filter(name -> !(name.contains("-value") || name.contains("-key")))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), "Some Reason"));
```

This is what I am getting:

> The method toMap(Function, Function) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Function, String)

No idea why I am not being able to do this... Everywhere I search the suggestions are basically the same as I am doing.

Comment: `invalidStrings = invalidSchemas = src.getAllSubjects()` what's this ? and what made you think of applying a string when for a similar argument you've applied a `Function.identity()` ?

Comment: That was a typo... will correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the important part of the error:

> The method toMap(Function, Function) **<--- note the `Function, Function`**

This means, `toMap` expects the first argument to be a function which you've done correctly via `Function.identity()` i.e. `v -> v` but the second value you've passed is a `String`

Rather the value mapper must be a function:

```
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> "Some Reason"));
```

note the `v -> "Some Reason"`;